# How to increase Video Memory on AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, windows-server

I am using Windows Server 2016 images (customized AMI) as Jenkins slaves. 
I need to increase the dedicated video memory of this instance to 8 MB. By default the video memory of Windows EC2 instances is 0 MB.

[image]

Kindly suggest a way for the same.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The low end windows instances do not have video memory. If you want your instances to have video memory, you have to launch G2 instances.

From [Amazon EC2 Instance Types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)

G2 instances are optimized for graphics-intensive applications.

**Features**:

- High Frequency Intel Xeon E5-2670 (Sandy Bridge) Processors
- High-performance NVIDIA GPUs, each with 1,536 CUDA cores and **4GB of video memory**
- Each GPU features an on-board hardware video encoder designed to support up to eight real-time HD video streams (720p@30fps) or up to four real-time full HD video streams (1080p@30fps)
- Support for low-latency frame capture and encoding for either the full operating system or select render targets, enabling high-quality interactive streaming experiences

**Use Cases**

3D application streaming, video encoding, and other server-side graphics workloads.

[image]